# Disable minicart dropdown on mobile devices

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, mobile-device

When on mobile devices, I want to **display the cart icon** on the **navbar** but on **clicking**, it should go directly to the **cart page**.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it by duplicating the .minicart-wrapper div inside of app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

You also need to remove the "showcart" class from the  tag immediately inside of #minicart-mobile. This will remove the dropdown functionality and  redirect you to the cart page.

I've hidden the desktop or mobile minicarts (as required) using bootstrap's d-none classes but you can achieve the same result using traditional CSS media queries

**Minicart Desktop**

```
<div id="minicart-desktop" data-block="minicart" class="d-none d-lg-block minicart-wrapper align-self-center mt-0">
    <a class="showcart" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getShoppingCartUrl() ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="counter qty empty d-flex"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number mx-auto"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
        <div class="minicart-container block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSerializedConfig() ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

**Minicart Mobile**

```
<div id="minicart-mobile" data-block="minicart" class="d-lg-none d-xl-none minicart-wrapper align-self-center mt-0">
    <a class="" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getShoppingCartUrl() ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="counter qty empty d-flex"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number mx-auto"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
        <div class="minicart-container block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSerializedConfig() ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to disable mini cart dropdown on mobile devices is to use a mixin. Create or use an existing module with the following code.

app/code/MagePal/MinicartOpen/view/frontend/web/js/dropdown-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function($){
    return function(){
        $.widget('mage.dropdownDialog', $.mage.dropdownDialog, {
            open:function(){
                var $cartLink = $('div.minicart-wrapper a.showcart');

                if (!$('.action.nav-toggle').is(":visible") || !$cartLink.length){
                    return this._super();
                } else {
                    window.location.href = $cartLink.attr("href");
                }
            }
        });

        return $.mage.dropdownDialog;
    };
});
```

The above code will check to see if the mobile hamburger menu is visible and redirect to the cart page if visible.

app/code/MagePal/MinicartOpen/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/dropdown': {
                'MagePal_MinicartOpen/js/dropdown-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I like this answer, it's not overriding any core files and is using Magento's recommended approach for extending JavaScript, i.e. [mixins](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html).
For my situation, I changed the if condition to `if (!this.element.hasClass('block-minicart') || window.innerWidth >= 768)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using luma theme classes then you can manage it by following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'], function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var $window = $(window);
            function checkWidth() {
                var windowsize = $window.width();
                if (windowsize < 440) {
                    $('.action.showcart').unbind('click');
                }
                else{
                    $('.action.showcart').bind('click');
                }
            }

            checkWidth();
            $(window).resize(checkWidth);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have added the above code to my phtml file you need to add this to your js file. Also here I mentioned the mobile device width(440). If the width is lower than 440 then minicart will not work and vice-versa.

Hope this helps!

***Note: Code was tested on Luma theme.***

Comment: We use Bootstrap for responsiveness and I've found that mixing jQuery and Bootstrap breakpoints doesn't always work very well. I managed to fix it using a slightly "hacky" method but it works perfectly! Will provide my solution as an answer.

Comment: Yes Please post your solution that will help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

I've made this into a Module for anyone that would like to use it!

Can be found here - https://github.com/joeyoung658/Magento2-DisableMoblieMiniCart

Based on @renon-stewart response!